# jQuery HTML5 Audio, alternate format for older browsers

Tags: jquery, html, audio, jquery-plugins

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to work a solution that will be able to play sound files on most browsers.  I have a working piece of code using jQuery and the audio support of HTML5.  It will support most of the new browsers but won't work with older browsers.

Is there a jQuery plugin that could work with the older browsers.  Worst case scenario, I can convert the mp3 files to swf and try to play them using jQuery, if possible.

Here's my code

```
<html>
 <head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var sound = $("#sound")[0];
        $("#play").mouseover(function() {
            sound.play();
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            sound.pause();
            sound.currentTime = 0;
        });     
    });  
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <audio id="sound">
        <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        Your browser doesn't support HTML5.
    </audio>

    <span id="play">Mouse over to play sound</span>

</body>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the following projects:

- [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)
- [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/)
- [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

All of them will use Flash on older browsers if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide a Flash player which can play MP3 files so that you can default to that. You should also provide a download link to the audio file in question just in case the user doesn't have Flash installed.

For example:

```
   <audio controls>
      <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf?audioUrl=sound.mp3" height="27" width="320">
         <param name="movie" value="player.swf?audioUrl=sound.mp3">
      </object>
      <a href="sound.mp3">Download the audio file</a>
   </audio>
```

You can see a working example [here](http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch3/audio-ogg-mp3-wav-flash-link.html).

You won't be able to access the Flash controls of the player via JavaScript though.